# Correctly referencing a JSON in Python. Strings versus Integers and Nested items

Tags: python, json, nested

Sample JSON file below

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "225 mi",
                  "value" : 361715
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
                  "value" : 13725
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I'm looking to reference the text value for distance and duration. I've done research but i'm still not sure what i'm doing wrong...

I have a work around using several lines of code, but i'm looking for a clean one line solution..

thanks for your help!

Comment: You forgot to show us your code. Are you using the standard `json` module to load that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the regular JSON module:

```
import json
```

And you're opening your JSON like this:

```
json_data = open("my_json.json").read()
data      = json.loads(json_data)

# Equivalent to:
data      = json.load(open("my_json.json"))

# Notice json.load vs. json.loads
```

Then this should do what you want:

```
distance_text, duration_text = [data['rows'][0]['elements'][0][key]['text'] for key in ['distance', 'duration']]
```

Hope this is what you wanted!

Comment: Oh now I see what I was doing wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, and if you liked my answer, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)